# How to replace WikiError::isError and WikiErrorMsg?

Tags: php, mediawiki

After searching by using Google for 1 hour, I found nothing.
So in the version v1.23 they removed the classes "WikiError" and "WikiErrorMsg".
How can I replace these functions from these classes in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`Status`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classStatus.html) is probably the best approach. `Status::newFatal( <message> )` to create an error, `Status::newGood( <result value> )` to create a successful result, `$status->isOK()` to check if the operation succeeded, then use `$status->getValue()` on success and `$status->getMessage()` on error.

In later MediaWiki versions (1.27+ if I remember correctly) `Status` is being phased out in favor of `StatusValue` - the most robust approach is to always return a `Status` but expect parameters to be `StatusValue`s.